# jQuery Sortable with static content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I writing a website by using Bootstrap and jQuery. Now, i have a horizontal list of div at the bottom of webpage. It's act like the Slide bar in Microsoft Powerpoint. The number is unchange element. If i got 6 record from server, it will generate 6 slide in the list. User can drag the "DIV" box and move to another position. Just like the normal flow of Sortable plugin.
[image]

Expected result:
[image]
I tried two way to code this "slide bar". However, i cannot build the expected result.

Concept 1:
Split two row to perform. but will have two scrollable.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 sortable-list">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Concept 2:
use "items". However, it will exist some weird issue when can drag the box. slideNumber div will move to wrong position and box will disappear

```js
$("sortable-list").sortable({
  items:'.box'
});
```

```css
.slideNumber{
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:15px;
}

.box{
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left:0;
}
/**roughly css**/
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 sortable-list">
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">1</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">2</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">3</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">4</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">5</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">6</div>
              <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can give me a hint to build this slide bar?

Comment: Add your CSS please

Comment: Because i cannot code the expected result, i just added roughly css on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
$( function() {
  $(".sortable-list")
    .sortable()
    .disableSelection();
} );
```

```css
.container > div {
  padding:0 30px 0px 30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.sortable-list > div {
  margin:1px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  background:#777;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 sortable-list">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row
{
width:100%;

}
 .col-md-12,.slideNumber
{
width:100%;
display:flex;
margin-right:50px;
}

.box
{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:gray;
text-align:center;
line-height: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 sortable-list">
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">1</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">2</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">3</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">4</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">5</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="slideNumber">6</div>
              <div class="box">Div</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is my second approach. it is possible to apply sortable plugin in this approach without re-position when you dragging the box.